# Jquery auto run pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create pagination with jquery , this script works fine , but i want the script works and call differents pages in automatic mode :

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#article_load_favourites").load("indexer_favourites_news.php");
});
</script>

<script>
function pagination(id)
{
$("#article_load_favourites").load("indexer_favourites_news.php?pg_d="+id);
}
```

/// Call the script function

```
setInterval(function() {

pagination(i+1);

}, 4000);



</script>
```

The idea it´s load the script and start from cero and before of 4 seconds go page number one and before of other 4 seconds go to the other page and continue to the end , in this point i try do this but no work me

I need run this script of pagination and go from page 1 to the last page and repit other time

Thank´s !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your HTML is not loaded yet when you call `setInterval`. Try moving `setInterval` inside `$(document).ready()` function.

```
<script>

function pagination(id)
{
  $("#article_load_favourites").load("indexer_favourites_news.php?pg_d="+id);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#article_load_favourites").load("indexer_favourites_news.php");

  var i = 1;

  setInterval(function() {
    pagination(i+1);
  }, 4000);
});

</script>
```